# Apache forward proxy using client certs for the backend

Tags: apache, ssl, proxy, mod-proxy, http-proxy

I have a set of backend API's which requires client certificate authentication. I would like to set up an Apache forward proxy, which will allow requests to be made to it via HTTP (within a private network), while Apache authenticates with a client cert to backend API's.

I am able to get this working when using Apache as a reverse proxy:

```
Listen 5454

<VirtualHost *:5454>

SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerifyDepth 10
SSLProxyMachineCertificateChainFile "/path/to/ca/ca.crt"
SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile "/path/to/cert/cert_and_key.pem"
SSLProxyVerify require

ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
  Require all granted
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / https://example.com/
ProxyPassReverse / https://example.com/

</VirtualHost>
```

Where the following returns content of https://example.com:

```
curl http://localhost:5454
```

However, when switching to a forward proxy configuration, the backend request is not authenticating with a client certificate:

```
Listen 5454

<VirtualHost *:5454>

SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerifyDepth 10
SSLProxyMachineCertificateChainFile "/path/to/ca/ca.crt"
SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile "/path/to/cert/cert_and_key.pem"
SSLProxyVerify require

ProxyRequests On

<Proxy *>
Require all granted
</Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

Where the following fails, appearing as if Apache is not using the client certs:

```
curl --proxy http://localhost:5454 https://www.example.com
curl: (56) NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)
```

Is there any configuration that I'm missing? Is it even possible to set up Apache in this way (or to even do this at all)? I'd happily welcome recommendations for alternatives!

Comment: Normally in front of a server (e.g. your API) you do place a reverse proxy, not a forward proxy.  Forward proxies need to be configured into the browsers, reverse proxies just look like the webserver.

Comment: In this case this is what I want - the clients for these API's will be configured for this.